# How do I make the link and the div element activate at the same time

Tags: html, css, button, hover

when i hover on the div element, only it lights up and not the link as well.
is there any way to make the button light up as one and not the button background and THEN the link.

```
<div id="b1"; class = b>
    <a href="test.html">BUY</a>
</div>

<div id="b2"; class = b>
    <a href="test.html">BUY</a>
</div>

<div id="b3"; class = b>
    <a href="test.html">BUY</a>
</div>
```

```
a:visited{
    color: white
}
a:hover:visited{
    color: rgb(180, 179, 179);
}

a:link{
    color: white;
    background-color:  rgb(180, 179, 179);
}
a:hover{
    color: rgb(180, 179, 179);   
    background-color: white    
}

div.b{
    color:  white;
    background-color: rgb(180, 179, 179);
}

div.b:hover{
    color: rgb(180, 179, 179);   
    background-color: white    
}
a:link { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; }
```

i tried everything at least i know of

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
.b:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.b:hover a {
  background: green;
}

/* or */
.b a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/roma3z/pen/QWxapdB

Comment: Also is there any way to make the whole thing clickable, not just the href?

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/roma3z/pen/QWxapdB